# 日本語と中国語の混ざった文を分ける方法はありますか？

Tags: 自然言語処理

多言語の音声合成をしたいんです。私の知る限り、日本語と中国語には同じ漢字がたくさんあります。もし日本語と中国語の混ざった文が来たら、どう分けるでしょうか？

例えば

- 日本最好的大学是 東京大学。（中 日）
- 我今年会去 横浜 旅行。（中 日 中）
- ティックトックは中国で 抖音 と呼ばれる。（日 中 日）

Comment: 文章単位であれば "cjk detect" 辺りで検索するといくつか手法が出てきますが、混ざった文が対象の場合は例で書かれているように予め分かち書きしておくか、「」で対象を明確にするなど工夫した方が現実的な気がします。

Comment: 個々の字～単語～文の何処から何処までが何の言語であるかの情報が存在するなら、その情報を残して連結することはこんな仕様を使えば出来ると思われます。[ISO-2022-JP-2: Multilingual Extension of ISO-2022-JP](http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/mendoxi/rfc/rfc1554j.html), [RFC 2822 - Internet Message Format 日本語訳](https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc2822.html) その情報が無いならAI/MLにでも掛けて明確な間違いが入り込むことを許容しつつ処理するとか？